# GraphQL querying database by passing it as one of resolve arguments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql

I am interested in learning GraphQL so I can build real fullstack apps.

I am trying to query my mongodb in my resolve function inside schema. I am getting error:

> "message": "mongodb.getCollection is not a function"

This is pretty straightforward, my mongodb argument has no getCollection function, the problem is I don't know why. I'm using mongodb, graphqlhttp, express-graphql.

Here's my code:

In my **index.js** file:

```
const graphql = express();
  graphql.use('/', graphQLHTTP(async () => ({
    graphiql: true,
    pretty: true,
    schema,
    context: {
      mongodb: await mongodb
    }
})));
```

In my schema file that's my resolve snippet:

```
resolve: async(source, { category }, { mongodb }) => {
  return await 
    stories: mongodb.getCollection('stories').find({})
  };
}
```

I am completly stuck at the moment, do you guys know what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I feel the issue is in the way you have set `mongodb` in context. Why do you need `await` before mongodb? Also it would be great if you could share code for initialising `mongodb` before setting it in context.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
  resolve: (obj, args, ctx) => {
    return mongodb.getCollection('stories').find({})
  }
```

needsless to say- the result from the DB should match the GraphQLObject type, something like:

```
new GraphQLList(storyType)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me atm, I'm still trying to figure out what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are using the `.find({})` function, its generally accepted to use GraphQLList as mentioned about, because it fetches everything from the database, and I suggest you make use of your **console.log();** more often. 
And from my own knowledge of graphQL, the resolve function accepts two params, the parent data and your args. 
Check Out this tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y0lDGjwRYKw) to better learn how to use GQL to query a mongodb.